# Using Firebase Auth with a Netlify hosted web app when 3rd party cookies are disabled

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

I have a web app hosted on Netlify (using React). I've set up Firebase Auth and it's working on my computer, but when I try to connect on my mobile I get the following error:
***"3rd party cookies and data may be disabled"***

I understand this is down to my own privacy settings and that this is going to be a frequent feature in modern browsers, so I need a workaround for this situation.

Is there a way to set up Firebase Auth so that I don't encounter this issue?

Comment: This issue is relevant, although there's currently not solution it seems: https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/issues/1040

Comment: Thanks Frank. I've decided I'll just host on Firebase and hope that resolves the issue.